# How two make a resource belong to two objects of the same model on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, relational-database

I have a model called Notes, i want a user which has a role attribute set as "teacher" to add notes to another user that has the role "student", but i want the notes to point to both, the teacher that created the note and the student for whom the note was written.

The problem that i find is that user is a single model that contains teachers and students, so how can i add two different user references to the same Notes object ?

This is how i usually create references `rails g migration AddUserToNotes user:references`, but that would only add one reference.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Well I am not advanced coder. But why not making students and teachers 2 different models ? Then you can make a polymorphic association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your migration and model this way.

```
create_table :notes do |t|
  t.integer  "teacher_id"
  t.integer  "student_id"
end

class Note < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :teacher, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Then you have

```
Note.create(teacher_id: 1, student_id: 2)
```

and so on...